# xterminal dosen't pass key-strokes to emacs

Tags: linux-mint, emacs, mate-desktop

I opened emacs using `emacs -nw`. Now, when I press <kbd>M</kbd>-<kbd>v</kbd>, it opens the view menu of the terminal, instead of passing the command to emacs. Is there a way to prevent this from happening? (I'm running on linux mint)

Comment: What is `xterminal`? Do you mean `xterm` or `gnome-terminal` or is this another terminal emulator?

Comment: @terdon I'm not sure how to check what terminal it is exactly, but the command that runs is `mate-terminal`

Comment: In that case, you are running `mate-terminal` :). It is a fork of `gnome-terminal` in case you're interested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that by <kbd>M</kbd>-<kbd>v</kbd> you actually mean <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> or, in emacspeak,  `^M-v`, you should be able to send `^M` by hitting <kbd>Esc</kbd> instead of <kbd>Alt</kbd>.

Just replace <kbd>Alt</kbd> with <kbd>Esc</kbd> for any `^M-` commands you want to run.

In the specific case of `mate-terminal`, you can switch off the shortcuts for the menus:

[image]

Then, deselect the "Enable menu access keys (such as Alt+F to open the File menu)" option:

[image]

Comment: I know about the Esc, but the Alt is much more accessible. Is there a way to use it?

Comment: @elyashiv see updated answer.